# how to save tree structure data in prisma

Tags: tree, nestjs, prisma, tree-structure

i try to build app with nestjs with prisma, i have problem with tree structure saving the data, here is my model for categories.

```
model Category {
  id   Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String

  children Category[] @relation("SubCategories")
  parent   Category?  @relation("SubCategories", fields: [parentId], references: [id])
  parentId Int?

  Product Product[]

  @@map("categories")
}
```

this is my logic:

```
async createCategory(dto: createCategoryDto) {
    const newCategory = await this.prisma.category.create({
        data: {
            name: dto.name,
            parent: dto.parentId
        }
    });
    return newCategory;
}
```

but when i am trying to save data, i got this error:

```
    ...
    [Nest] 30699  - 07/06/2022, 1:31:36 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] 
    Invalid `this.prisma.category.create()` invocation in
    /home/fadhli/SandBox/lanjo/lanjo-api/src/category/category.service.ts:26:56
    
      23 }
      24 
      25 async createCategory(dto: createCategoryDto) {
    → 26     const newCategory = await this.prisma.category.create({
               data: {
                 name: 'example',
                 parentId: '1'
                 ~~~~~~~~
               }
             })
    
    Unknown arg `parentId` in data.parentId for type CategoryCreateInput. Did you mean `parent`? Available args:
    type CategoryCreateInput {
      name: String
      children?: CategoryCreateNestedManyWithoutParentInput
      parent?: CategoryCreateNestedOneWithoutChildrenInput
      Product?: ProductCreateNestedManyWithoutCategoryInput
    }
```

how to save tree data into database in nestjs and prisma?

thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? If so, would you share your solution? I'm trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify, how relation should occur: do you want to `connect` an existing record as `parent`, or do you want to `create` it inline. For example:

```js
const newCategory = await this.prisma.category.create({
    data: {
        name: dto.name,
        parent: {
            connect: {
                id: dto.parentId,
            },
        },
    }
});
```